# Slicing and Indexing a Series in Python

Tags: python, indexing, scikit-learn, slice, series

I am learning Python and Scikit learn and I am doing some simple exercises.  In the particular case I run the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('SMSSpamCollection',delimiter='\t',header=None)  # from UCIMachineLearningRepository http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/SMS+Spam+Collection
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.linear_model.logistic import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split, cross_val_score
X_train_raw, X_test_raw, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df[1], df[0])
```

I print:

```
print(X_test_raw[0:5])
```

output:

```
3035      Get ready for  &lt;#&gt;  inches of pleasure...
2577                 In sch but neva mind u eat 1st lor..
3302             RCT' THNQ Adrian for U text. Rgds Vatian
90      Yeah do! Don‘t stand to close tho- you‘ll catc...
2355                 R we going with the  &lt;#&gt;  bus?
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

Then I am indexing one by one the first elements of the Series X_test_raw:

```
X_test_raw[0]
```

out

```
'Go until jurong point, crazy.. Available only in bugis n great world la e buffet... Cine there got amore wat...'
```

then

```
X_test_raw[1]
```

out

```
'Ok lar... Joking wif u oni...'
```

then

```
X_test_raw[2]
```

out

```
KeyError: 2L
```

What is going on?  Why I get different values returned when I am slicing the first 5 elements sequence and when I am indexing each element of this sequence separately?  Why I get a key error message when I am indexing the 3d element of the Series?

Your advice will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If use `X_test_raw[2]` you try get `row` with `index=2`, but if missing get:

> KeyError: 2L

For select by position need [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iloc.html) or [`iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iat.html):

```
X_test_raw.iloc[2]
```

Sample:

```
s = pd.Series(['a','s','f'], index=[2,3,5])
print (s)
2    a
3    s
5    f
dtype: object

print (s[2])
a

print (s[1:3])
3    s
5    f
dtype: object

print (s.loc[2])
a


print (s.iloc[2])
f
```

You can check:

- [slicing ranges](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#slicing-ranges)
- [select by label](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-label)
- [select by position](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-position)